# How can I parse out text from a string containing HTML identifiers?

Tags: c#

I have web pages that contain text areas with HTML inside of them. For example here's a sample of text:

```
var a = "some text follows<p><p>Give the following test text:</p>
<pre>abc {<br />    int size;<br />    String name;<br />    Test ( String name, int size ) {<br />        this.name = name;<br />        this.size = size;<br />    }<br>"
```

I want to set the META description for my web pages with the text above after the HTML has been removed.

Does anyone have any idea how I can remove the HTML from text. I don't need have anything fancy. Maybe even just removing everything that's within and including the angle brackets would do the trick?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
var a = "some text follows<p><p>Give the following test text:</p>"

var newString = Regex.Replace(a, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Result

```
some text followsGive the following test text:
```

Comment: To the downvoter could you specify the reason for the downvote here. this does note make sense. since this is not wrong solution and the poster specify that `I don't need have anything fancy. Maybe even just removing everything that's within and including the angle brackets would do the trick`...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string html = "your html text";
string result = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html);
```

Or:

```
string html = "your html text";
string result = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(html);
```

Test:

```
var a = "some text follows<p><p>Give the following test text:</p>
<pre>abc {<br />    int size;<br />    String name;<br />    Test ( String name, int size ) {<br />        this.name = name;<br />        this.size = size;<br />    }<br>"
```

Result:

```
"some text follows&lt;p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Give the following test text:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;pre&gt;abc {&lt;br /&gt;    int size;&lt;br /&gt;    String name;&lt;br /&gt;    Test ( String name, int size ) {&lt;br /&gt;        this.name = name;&lt;br /&gt;        this.size = size;&lt;br /&gt;    }&lt;br&gt;"
```